# Regex for phone number in international format

Tags: php, regex, validation, symfony

I need to write a regex that will match only this formats

```
+420 000 000 000
+420000000000
420 000 000 000
420000000000
```

It can't match any a-z character in any part of string, just numbers, white space and "+" on the beginning.

Answer (score 7):

You could try the below regex,

```
^\+?\d{3} ?\d{3} ?\d{3} ?\d{3}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sY1nH4/2)

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `\+?` optional `+`
- `\d{3}` Matches exactly three digits.
- `<space>?` optional space
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Comment: Working perfectly, if i would love to add one more?

Comment: 0905 222 222 for example?

Comment: @user1999739 My answer/ regex should work for your example(`0905 222 222`)!

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you:

```
$mobileNumber = "0905 222 222";

 if ( preg_match("/^(\+?)([0-9] ?){9,20}$/", $mobileNumber) )
            echo "matches!";
```